# Trouble with inserting an user in test class

Tags: failing-tests

I am trying to insert a profile called "Vendor Partner Portal" for a user in my test class. When I run the tests I am getting an error message saying

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): User, original object: Product_Line__c: []
>
> Stack Trace: Class.Test_salesQuotes.runasPartner: line 230, column 1

Below is my code. Can someone help me find what the issue is

```
    @isTest()
    public class Test_salesQuotes{
     public static  testMethod  void runasPartner() {

         Product_Line__c pl = new Product_Line__c(name = 'myPL');
      insert pl;     

     Product2 p = new product2(name='gack',family='gack',productcode='gack',Product_Line__c=pl.Id,isActive=true);
      insert p;

       Product2 p3 = new product2(name='gack',family='gack',productcode='gack',Product_Line__c=pl.Id,isActive=true);
       p3.Loanable__c=true;
      insert p3;
  Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();     
      try{
          insert new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id = pricebookId , product2id = p.id, 
                                unitprice=1.0, isActive=true);
      }catch(System.DMLException e){
        //Swallow exception - creating the product2 should have created a standard 
        //PricebookEntry already.
      }

        Pricebook2 pb = new pricebook2(name='test', Ext_Ref_Id__c='asldfjlakjsdf234234');
        insert pb;
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(pricebook2id=pb.id, product2id=p.id, 
                                              unitprice=1.0, isActive=true);
        insert pbe;

       Opportunity o = new Opportunity(name='test', pricebook2id=pb.id,
        stageName='Open', CloseDate=Date.newInstance(2006,10,10));
        insert o;
        OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(opportunityid=o.id, 
                                pricebookentryid=pbe.id, unitprice=1.5, quantity=2);
        insert oli;

     SFDC_520_Quote__c q = new SFDC_520_Quote__c(Opportunity__c = o.id); 
    insert q;

      id VendorPQRecordType = [select Id FROM RecordType where Name = 'Primary Cells Request'].Id;

       SFDC_520_Quote__c q1 = new SFDC_520_Quote__c(Opportunity__c = o.id); 
         q1.recordtypeid=VendorPQRecordType;
     insert q1;

    PageReference pageRef = Page.AddQuoteLines;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
      system.debug( 'quote id is '+q.id);

      ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', q.id);

     salesQuotes s = new salesQuotes();
     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('reloadQuote','1');

     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', q1.id);

     salesQuotes s1 = new salesQuotes();
     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('reloadQuote','1');

     ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('userTypeName', null);

     system.assertEquals('Standard',s1.UserTypeName);

        Account acct = test_standardobjectutil.createAccount('Test Account', false);
    // acct.IsPartner=true;
     insert acct;

     Contact c = test_standardobjectutil.createContact('John','Doe2', false);
     c.accountid = acct.Id;
     insert c;  

     Profile userProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Vendor Partner Portal']; 
     User u = new User(Alias = 't23', Email='teststandarduser@stemcell.com', 
     EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
     LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = userProfile.Id,
     ContactId = c.id,
     TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='teststandarduser@stemcell.com');
     insert u;
        system.runAs(u){

            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('pid', p.id);
             s.enableAddProducts();
             s.searchStr='g';
            system.debug('Test exact user:'+ u); 
            s.doSearch(); 
        }
   }
   }
```

Comment: is that my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2):

Create a @testSetup method and create user, account and other record which can be used across methods in same test class.

```
@testSetup static void setup() {

     Account acct = test_standardobjectutil.createAccount('Test Account', false);
    // acct.IsPartner=true;
     insert acct;

     Contact c = test_standardobjectutil.createContact('John','Doe2', false);
     c.accountid = acct.Id;
     insert c;  

     Profile userProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Vendor Partner Portal']; 
     User u = new User(Alias = 't23', Email='teststandarduser@stemcell.com', 
     EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
     LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = userProfile.Id,
     ContactId = c.id,
     TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName='teststandarduser@stemcell.com');
     insert u;        
}
```

In the test method retrieve the user and use accordingly.

```
User u = [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Email='teststandarduser@stemcell.com'];
system.runAs(u){

}
```

You should be writing test class following [Testing best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm)